# Add-Computer adds VM to domain then WMI fails

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am currently trying to add a Windows Server 2016 Vm to our domain using the following command.

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName $ServerName -NewName $ServerName -LocalCredential $localCreds -Credential $adcreds -DomainName mydomain.net -OUPath $ou -Force
```

The command creates the AD computer object and renames the server pending its reboot.

However, the cmdlet runs for about 15 minutes then gives us the following error:

```
Add-Computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'SERVER' with the following error message: The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE).
```

We are not experiencing this issue at all with our Windows Server 2012 R2 Build.

Comment: The error message is basically: "The computer sending the command can't talk to `$ServerName`". Check that you passed the correct name in `$ServerName` and that a firewall isn't blocking the communication.

Comment: @BenH I understand what the error means, however...  While I am attempting to run the powershell command from a remote server, I am actually RDP'd into the target server with the local credentials. The powershell on the remote server will fail, and about 20 seconds later I will get kicked out of my RDP session with the target server, and it will come back up on the domain I specified in the powershell. It is very odd behavior.

Comment: Possibly WMI out is blocked. Can you check that it's open? Here's an example command to open it if it isn't. Also the link has all the steps to verify that WMI is open. [`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=out name ="WMI_OUT" program=%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe service=winmgmt action=allow protocol=TCP localport=any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj980508(v=winembedded.81).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like failed authentication. You can try to connect to the remote computer by the following code example:

```
Net use \$servername\IPC$ /User:Administrator $LocalCreds.GetNetworkcredential().password
```

After that, try your command again.

Comment: I understand what the error means, however...  While I am attempting to run the powershell command from a remote server, I am actually RDP'd into the target server with the local credentials. The powershell on the remote server will fail, and about 20 seconds later I will get kicked out of my RDP session with the target server, and it will come back up on the domain I specified in the powershell. It is very odd behavior.

Comment: So, it’s rebooting without applying the switch to restart?

Comment: Yes. The powershell is failing after about 7-10 minutes. As soon as it fails, the server reboots and is on the domain.